# How can I make Stellarium match the magnitude of stars visible in London, UK?

Tags: star-gazing, software, light-pollution

Can someone recommend some Stellarium settings to mimic the amount of light pollution, and magnitude of stars that should be visible on a clear night in London, UK?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it depends on where in London you are. In downtown Albuquerque (for example), it's hard to see magnitude 3 stars, but, near the city limits, you can often see magnitude 6 stars. Rule of thumb: how many stars can you see in Ursa Minor (the Little Bear aka the Little Dipper)? The main stars in this constellation happen to be magnitude 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Answer (score 6):

Ok go on Stellarium then hover over the left side of the screen afterwards click on the location and select London, England (City Of London is the original walled city), then go and hover over the left side of the screen and select sky and viewing options and in the sky section and select the air pollution level from location database then it will automatically set the air pollution depending on where you are on Earth, cool right?